# Opening Multiple files one time in Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to load multiple files at one time; I mean that when the open dialog file comes up, I want to be able to select multiple files and then hold the path of them. I know the FileReference Class but it will only get one file at a time. so is there a way to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FileReferenceList class. This works similarly as the FileReference class you mentioned.

For more info check out the docs:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReferenceList.html